# Polymorphism , c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Assume there are class A , and class B that inherits A. what is the correct way to use B objects?
I've seen in "cplusplus.com" that they are "using" B objects this way:

```
B b;
A* a=&b;
```

What's the difference between using a class "A" pointer and using b?

Thanks!

Comment: Start from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Please read some introductory book first.

Comment: what's the point of polymorphism?

Comment: No difference, that's the point.

Comment: @Lol4t0: There are plenty of differences.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yeah, but that's _not_ the point. Don't be boring.

Comment: @Lol4t0: Don't be misleading to fragile language newcomers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of using pointers to base classes comes when you have virtual functions.
 Imagine the following

```
class A {
    A(){}
    virtual ~A(){} // note virtual destructor
    virtual void func(){ cout << "A func" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
    B(){}
    virtual ~B(){}
    virtual void func(){ cout << "B func" << endl; }
};

class C : public A {
    C(){}
    virtual ~C(){}
    virtual void func(){ cout << "C func" << endl; }
}
```

now if we have a pointer to base class we can call `func()` on it and the correct function is called depending on whether the pointer actually points at an `A`, a `B` or a `C`. Example:

```
A* p1 = new A;
A* p2 = new B;
A* p3 = new C;
p1->func();
p2->func();
p3->func();
```

will output the following

```
A func
B func
C func
```

Now you may say why not use three different pointers to A, B and C types separately but what if you wanted an array of pointers? Then they would all need to be the same type, namely `A*`. This type of polymorphism is useful for grouping things which are similar in function or spirit but different in implementation.

Answer (score 2):

They only did that to show that you *can*, and that polymorphism is invoked when you do.

If you just want to use your `B b`, just use it; no `A*` required.

As an aside, learning C++ from internet tutorials is rather akin to learning how to cook by analysing some chewing gum you found in the street. Prefer [a proper, peer-reviewed book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).